# Can't create an object with syntax <interface>{} anymore?

Tags: typescript

The following code produces an error in the typescript playground:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const makePerson= function(name : string, age : number) : Person {
    
    let obj = <Person>{}
    obj.name = name;
    obj.age = age;
    return obj  
}
```

The code produces a red squiggly under 'person' `let obj = <Person>{}`

I use this syntax to create objects conforming to an interface all the time.  Did something change in the language?  Is something broken in the playground?  Why does the error message talk about React?  Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It's being interpreted as a JSX opening tag. But also it's better to `return { name, age }`, so there's no point when the object isn't valid as a Person.

Comment: I don't get it.  This is valid typescript which runs fine in VS Code. I don't use react.  Why doesn't work int he playground? (and, I have the same question as azium)

Comment: I think that you can use `const obj={} as Person` -well, const or let-

Comment: Maybe but I have this syntax for object creation sprinkled throughout my codebase.  Just trying to figure out if this is some glitch in the playground or some change in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, according to Ryan Cavanaugh, this is the expected behavior in the playground, although `let x = <interface>{}` is valid Typescript syntax for creating an object which supports a particular interface.  His explanation: "The Playground uses .tsx behind the scenes since people writing React snippets there is anecdotally more common than using the expr type assertion syntax."